# "How long is a Jewish wedding?"

Tags: gentiles, wedding

If someone who's not familiar with Jewish customs is invited to a Jewish wedding and comes to you to ask how long to plan to be there, how do you respond?

It's easy enough to say "It can vary a great deal; ask the people who invited you," but that's not terribly helpful. Is there a clear, brief way to explain how long to expect to stay, perhaps taking into account what parts of the wedding the asker is [likely] most interested in being there for?

---

I don't recall having received such a query personally, but I believe that it's not an uncommon one. Our treatment of a [similar question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/287/how-long-is-a-jewish-funeral) about funerals that I *was* asked become one of our few ["Notable"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/47/notable-question) questions recently, indicating that it's something that people search for on the Internet. If you go to [Google](http://google.com) and start typing `How long is a Jewish`, Google suggests completions of first `wedding` and then `funeral`, indicating that people tend to search even more for answers to this question about weddings. It therefore seems worthwhile to be prepared to answer this question as well.

Comment: So much of this is community/culture and other variable based. A room is often rented for 4-5 hours so maybe that is a good number. or 1 hour for the shmorg, 1 for the entire chupah and 2-3 for the meal/dancing? But some weddings are structured differently so there can't be a universal answer. For the parts that make it a "Jewish" wedding, i bet you can get it all done in under 30 minutes, no frills, beginning to end.

Comment: @Danno, so are you proposing an answer or answering "no"?

Comment: I think the meta section is out of scope. Worthy of a comment, definitely. +1

Comment: @SethJ, It goes to the motivation of the question. I haven't dealt with the question personally (that I recall), but I have evidence that it's one worth being prepared for.

Comment: I think we've pretty well established that a good question needn't arise from personal experience on our site, so I think the motivation is covered in your first pgh.

Comment: @SethJ, But the motivation ought to come from somewhere. If it was *just* a hypothetical from my imagination, why should anyone care to answer? In fact, the motivation for this question comes from evidence, so that evidence is at least relevant.

Comment: @IsaacMoses without followup questions and clarifying points, I think "no."

Comment: Do you see "...and what happens at one?" as part of this question too, or separate?

Comment: @MonicaCellio The intent of this question is to be equipped to answer the very simple "how long" question, since it is likely to at least sometimes come by itself from someone mainly interested in logistics (as it did for me with the funeral question and as it does in searches). A good answer *may* require getting into some nuance about what happens when. The separate "what happens" question is definitely worthy, but I feel that it's probably already treated pretty well by the Internet, since you can find many good summaries out there that directly address this question for outsider audiences.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, with all due respect to Rabbi Google, I don't think the fact that people search for a question is a good indicator that the question is, in fact, a good one. If you search "Do Jews", Google insta-search gives you "go to Heaven" as one of the top search terms. Add the word "have" to your search, and you get a long list of searches that could inspire protests in Mountainview, CA.

Comment: @SethJ Do you think I should add some language about why I think this commonly-searched question, in particular, is worth knowing how to answer?

Comment: My comment apparently got gobbled up. I tried to say that I favor contracting, not expanding, this question.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70816

Answer (score 5):

<sub>(I'm sure that different communities vary wildly, so I'll answer for the one I'm most familiar with, the Chabad community. Even in narrowing it to this, there will still be quite a bit of variation depending on locale, time of year, etc. If it's just the rabbi that's Chabad, and not the family, these rules will likely not apply.)</sub>

**TL;DR**
A Chabad wedding can last between 3 and 6 hours, and occasionally more. You are not required to stay all the way.

---

There are four main parts to the wedding. [Kabbalas Panim](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/477332/jewish/Kabbalat-Panim-Pre-Chupah-Reception.htm), Chupa, dinner, and dancing. Some people stay for all four, others, for just the second or third, and still others come for just the fourth. From start to finish, a wedding can run from 3 to 6 hours. Generally, family and close friends stick it all the way out, while others (especially those with children) often leave earlier. There are exceptions to both, and you're unlikely to offend anyone either way.

**Kabbalas Panim** is the reception. Usually held in two separate rooms, one each for men and women. Light refreshments are often served, the groom will repeat a [maamar](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/531523/jewish/Lecha-Dodi-Chassidic-Discourses.htm) and the tenaim are read.

**Chupa!** is the actual wedding ceremony. Very solemn until breaking the glass, then very happy. Usually takes place outside, and lasts anywhere from 20 to 60 minutes, depending on a number of factors (location, singing, weather, etc.) You **won't** get a chance to speak to the groom or bride, so if you want to wish them "Mazel Tov!" you'll have to stick around for the next part.

**Dinner!** !רצה לבנינו, על כן התחתנו, בוא נאכל
While the bride and groom head to the yichud room to break their fast, you'll head to the dining hall. May be just inside the building, down the block, or across town. Usually one of the first two. Dinner feels like it must be between 45 and 75 minutes (I've never checked); the groom and bride will come out near the beginning. This may be your chance to wish them "Mazel Tov!" Often, the groom will go around the men's side with a bottle, offering people a L'chaim.

**Dancing!** The part we've all been waiting for. As the band kicks up, everyone will head to the middle of the room for some serious hora. Ok, fine, it's not the hora. This part can get a little crazy, and by now you've probably lost your chance to speak to either of the couple, unless you're willing to stick it out till benching at the end. Dancing can run anywhere from 2 hours to 4+ (people will drop out of the circle throughout to rest and refresh). Since Chabad weddings usually start mid to late afternoon, the dancing often ends between 11 and 1 o'clock. There is no obligation to stick it out, and often by the end of it, many of the people remaining are relatives and close friends. Often there are bochurim, and others, still around, waiting to [bentch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkat_Hamazon) and say [sheva brachos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheva_Brachot) at the end.

---

<sup>Note: This is my experience, garnered from the weddings to which I've been. Feel free to correct anything I've gotten wrong or missed, or to broaden it to include your experience (for example, I have little knowledge of the kabbolas panim and what's going on on the women's side). If you feel this is similar enough to other customs and want include those, go ahead; just make sure to edit in which groups it applies to.</sup>

Comment: Why doesn't Chupa get an exclamation? To some, _this_ is what we've all been waiting for!

Comment: @SethJ Fixed :) Originally I left it out since it's a very solemn event.

Comment: To my knowledge at most weddings one eats or breaks his/her fast in the yichud room. I am surprised that chabad dont have this minhag. Perhaps you can tell us what they do in the yichud room.

Comment: In Belz although they have separated rooms for men and women. The groom eats with his bride in the ladies room before going into the mens room.

Comment: At the kabolas ponim the kesuba is read witnessed and signed. I find the chabad minhag of the tanoim instead remarkable.

Comment: @annex I believe you're right about breaking the fast. My mistake.

Comment: @annex I'm actually a bit foggy on the kesuba and the tenaim. I know that the tenaim are read at the kabbalas panim and the kesuba under the chupa, but I'm confused about their signing. I've seen and read several ways, but I'm unsure as to the "official" custom. Someone with more knowledge and experience will hopefully help out.

Comment: @annex, in my experience (various Ashkenazi in US, including Chabad), to my memory, both documents are signed at the tisch, but only the tenaim are read then, while the ketuba is read under the chuppa.

Comment: At my cousin's wedding last month, the mesader kiddushin (HaRav Yehuda Landau of Tel Aviv) had the eidim sign the ketubah during the chatan's kabbalat panim. As I'm related to the kallah, I arrived late at his side of things, so I don't know if/when the tenaim was read.

Comment: yuo may want to adapt this answer for http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70816/759