# Why do Chabad wedding invitations show the wrong time?

Tags: minhag, wedding, chabad

It has recently [come to my attention](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70818/1713) that Chabad wedding invitations in the US are often bilingual Hebrew/English and the time given for the wedding on the Hebrew side is wrong (perhaps a copy of the Rebbe's invitation?). Can anyone shed any light on what this is and why it's done?

Comment: http://www.shturem.net/index.php?section=artdays&id=181 http://www.teshura.com/teshurapdf/Gneivish-Kaltman%20-%20Cheshvan%2013%2C%205776.pdf

Comment: @Dude Most I've seen put the correct time in a footnote

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be caused by the Rebbe's [sicha](https://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/10/24/197.htm) which says to put this time (and to copy the Rebbe's if there minhagim became public, but specifically by weddings, by a marriage ain sof power is needed the leader of the generation brings it to us so we should act like him)

> י. האמור לעיל הוא בנוגע למנהגים בכלל. ובפרט בנוגע למנהגי חתונה – ה"ז בודאי נוגע לכל, שהרי בנישואין צריך להתגלות כח האין-סוף ב"דור ישרים יבורך", וכיון שהתגלות כח הא"ס נמשכת ע"י נשיא הדור, לכן נוגע יותר **שתהי' ההנהגה במנהגי בית הרב**.
> ...

> יב. בנוסח ההזמנה של החתונה – נוסח ההזמנה לחתונתו של הרבי, ובמילא כן הוא גם בנוסח ההזמנה ששלח הרבי לחתונת בנותיו ("זיינע קינדער'ס חתונה") – הי' כתוב זמן החופה בשעה החמישית בערב.

> **הן כשהיתה החתונה בחורף והן כשהיתה החתונה בקיץ – כתבו תמיד זמן החופה בשעה החמישית בערב.**

> **החופה עצמה נערכה אמנם בלילה**,

> – בחתונתי נערכה החופה בשעה מאוחרת ביותר ("גאָר שפּעט"), בגלל טעם חיצוני –

> **אבל ה"קבלת פנים" – דייקו שתתחיל בשעה החמישית.** (ולא כמו שנהוג כאן, שכותבים שעה פלונית, ובפועל מתחילים שעתיים לאחרי כן...)

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180916214047/http://www.insidechassidus.org/sichos/288-toras-menachem/1492-vayishlach-14-kislev-5714.html) is audio of the sicha.

Comment: Hmm... But why? Maybe there's just no reason?

Comment: @Daniel "It's done" because the rebbe said to do it.   If you ask me go guess why then I guess that it is a good sign (as a lot of things by weding) to do it then https://books.google.com/books?id=VFzpAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA428&lpg=PA428&dq=created+on+friday+5th+hour+torah&source=bl&ots=LTXqaLH2Fy&sig=82302dmWy1YHijZw8X-ijDkC-8Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-x6y-vcrMAhWIgj4KHY8sA4EQ6AEIIjAD#v=onepage&q=created%20on%20friday%205th%20hour%20torah&f=false and שעה חמישית עמד על רגליו, זו מדרגת האדם ההולך קומם מפני שהוא מלך הנמצאים התחתונים, ולמלך ראוי שיהיה בזקיפה. ויש בזה עוד דברים נפלאים, ונתבאר בדרך החיים and

Comment: סנהדרין · לח:  חמישית עמד על רגליו

Comment: @Dude I did not see anything regarding the place, if says you need to put the time the 5th hour (but the chupa needs to be at night) but the kabolas ponom should be at the 5th house and not late but as it says