# A wedding invitation insert to insert into a wedding invitation to inform secular friends and family about the customs of a religious jewish wedding

Tags: minhag, wedding, secular-culture

Is there a wedding invitation insert (in pdf or other presentable formats) somewhere online that one may freely use to insert into a Jewish wedding invitation to inform secular friends and family about the customs and procedures of a jewish wedding to ensure that everyone is comfortable and to avoid any room for embarrassment?

Comment: Probably best to write your own as everyone has some different customs and practices.

Comment: Something small enough to be inserted into the invitation will invariably omit or shortchange certain practices. Sites like this http://www.aish.com/jl/l/m/48969841.html link to a pdf which can be sent out or distributed but it wouldn't make for a great insert.

Comment: Very closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70816/472

Comment: Many people will have a couple of pages at the reception before the wedding (or at the wedding) for people to take and read. That way it can have enough information and be big enough to be useful. Many cateres have a standard handout to use.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Practically, though, I suspect that many of your guests may be overwhelmed and may not bother reading it. I don't know your crowd or community, but, in my area, most people just sned the response card (some don't, but that's a separate problem) and discard or lose the invitation. At any rate, I think distributing these at the wedding itself, makes a better impression. Another idea may be to include a card that has links to the info. Or, I've heard of many couples having a wedding "blog", so you can place the info there. It's a lot cheaper this way, too.